# $U(1)$ Chern-Simons from simple integer quantum Hall arguments, basics

Tags: quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

I am trying to understand how the Chern-Simons term appear in $U(1)$ effective theory of integer quantum Hall effect (IQHE). I usually read in (90% of) lecture notes "$A dA  $ is the Chern-Simons term. This is the only term that works,... QED". I am not satisfied (even the Chern-Simons professor of Berkley is satisfied by this proof so maybe I am missing something). Other arguments are rotational and gauge invariance, relevance of paramter in the long wave-length, so this is a smart term to think about but I have a basic mind.
I hence try to build a proof, from simple arguments. However, I am missing a piece. It is not rigorous, so please help complete and solidify it, or redirect to materials. Here is what I have:

For IQHE the conductivity $\sigma_{ij}=\nu e^2/h\epsilon^{ij}=\sigma_h \epsilon^{ij}$ with $\epsilon^{ij}$ the antisymmetric 2x2 tensor and roman letters $\in \{1,2\}$.
\begin{equation}
\langle j_i\rangle=\frac{\int Dc \frac{\delta S}{\delta A^i}e^{-S[c,A]}}{Z[A]}=\frac{\delta \ln Z[A]}{\delta A^i}=-\frac{\delta S_{eff}[A]}{\delta A^i}=\sigma_{ij}E_j=\sigma_h \epsilon^{ij}E_j=\sigma_h \epsilon^{ij} \partial_\tau A_j
\end{equation}
For some euclidean action $S$ coupling electrons and potential, and $Z[A]=e^{-S_{eff}[A]}$.
The continuity equation $\partial_0 j^0+ \nabla . j=0$ can be used for the last equality of $\partial_\tau j^0=\partial_\tau\frac{\delta S_{eff}[A]}{\delta A^0}=-\partial_\tau\partial_i\epsilon^{ij}A_j$, hence$ \frac{\delta S_{eff}[A]}{\delta A^0}=-\epsilon^{ij}\partial_i A_j$

The target is $\epsilon^{\mu \nu\lambda} A_\mu \partial_\nu A_\lambda$. So far we have: $A_x (\partial_\tau A_y - ...)+A_y (... -\partial_\tau A_x)+A_0(\partial_y A_x -\partial_x A_y)$.

- How do I get the two missing terms?
- Is there another way to get all the terms of Chern-Simons from simple IQHE observations?

Comment: The two missing terms are required to be there for gauge invariance. Even you said you are not satisfied with gauge invariance, it is a defining principle of gauge theory, so whenever you write anything with A's the action needs to be gauge invariant.

Comment: You may want to look at the paper by Zhang, Hansson, and Kivelson if you haven't already. It's hardly a proof, but it does motivate the Chern-Simons action starting from the microscopic theory.

Comment: @MengCheng I am satisfied with gauge invariance as long as I know the right time to use it and I can verify there was no other way to go further - Is it possible to identify and recover the missing terms from the non-gauge-invariant result that I have, by imposing gauge invariance ?

Comment: Also in the last step of your equation for $\langle j_i\rangle$, you used $E_i=\partial_\tau A_i$. But it should be $E_i=\partial_\tau A_i-\partial_i A_0$, unless you fix the gauge to be $A_0=0$. If you actually fix this gauge, then the terms you have obtained are already gauge-invariant (for the remaining gauge transformations after fixing $A_0=0$).

Comment: @MengCheng Indeed thanks for spotting. I am close to calling it a try. Maybe you could help on one last thing. In "Appendix: Building an Effective
(Chern-Simons) Field Theory" of Steve Simons TopoBook, he does the following: $j^0=\frac{\delta B}{2\pi m}$, and $j^i=-\frac{\epsilon_{ij}E^j}{2\pi m}$, can both be put into the form $j^\mu=-\frac{\epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda }\partial_\nu \delta A_\lambda}{2\pi m}$. From charge conservation $j^\mu=-\frac{\epsilon_{\mu \nu \lambda} \partial_\nu a_\lambda}{2\pi}$. 
What is the subtlety between $\delta A_\lambda$ and $a_\lambda$ ? Isn't $j$ $\delta j$?

Comment: $j^\mu = - \epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu \delta A_\lambda/2\pi m$ is the response of the QH state to an external EM field. So the action $\frac{1}{4\pi m}AdA$ is really the response theory, i.e. it only tells you how the system responds to external $A$ fields. When writing $j^\mu= - \epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu \delta a_\lambda/2\pi $, typically the purpose is to motivate an effective gauge theory for the QH state itself, so $a_\mu$ is treated as a dynamical variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MengCheng